# template for all container types with features begin() end() size()

Tags: c++, templates

The following template code is written for vectors. It does not compile because of one call is using list rather than vector. I want to rewrite the template so that it works for any container. The restrictions on that container are that it needs to contain a type T, have a begin(), have an end() and have a size();

Can this be done with templates?
How would I do that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace std
{
    template <typename T>
    string to_string(T s) { return typeid(T).name(); }
    string to_string(string s) { return s; }
}

template<typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
static std::string range_to_string(std::vector<T, A> const& vec)
{
    bool more = false;
    std::string str = "size:" + std::to_string(vec.size()) + " [";
    for (const T & item : vec)
    {
        if (more) { str += ", "; }
        str += std::to_string(item);
        more = true;
    }
    str += "]";
    return str;
}

void demo1()
{
    std::string dat[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
    std::vector<std::string> vs(dat, dat + 3);
    std::cout << range_to_string(vs) << std::endl;
}

void demo2()
{
    std::list<short> ls= {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::cout << range_to_string(ls) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    demo1();
    demo2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use iterators pointing to the beginning and ending values instead of the entire container?  Then you could use regular old arrays as well as vector, list, deque, etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure adding those declarations to `std` is undefined behaviour. You should just define them in your own namespace (or the global one) and use ADL.

Comment: So you have to make a function that can only take a type that has `begin()`, `end()` and `size()` or you have to make a function and all you know is that type passed will have `begin()`, `end()` and `size()`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Good Idea. The Target Codebase is free of arrays though. With a bit of boiler code this can be slapped on.

Comment: @TartanLlama I will remove that from the Production code.

Comment: @NathanOliver I actually thought I would get compiler errors if I use begin without declaring that my template has to feature that. I think I need to revisit templates.

Comment: @Johannes You will it just depends where the error come from.  If you just take any type and then try to call begin if it doesn't have it then you will get a compiler error on that line in the function.  The other way to do is to use SFINAE and you will get a compiler error on the function itself is the container does not satisfy the requirements.

Comment: @SirDarius - it's not just `to_string(string)` that's illegal. `template <class T> to_string(T)` is, too, since it, too, does not have any user-defined type as a parameter. This code simply does not belong in `std`.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes, I retract my previous statement, to_string is not a template function anyways, so UB all the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=376878).

It looks like this is common knowledge.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace std
{
    template <typename T>
    string to_string(T s) { return typeid(T).name(); }
    string to_string(short s) { return to_string((int) s); }
    string to_string(string s) { return s; }
}

template<typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>, template <typename, typename> class container>
static std::string range_to_string(container<T, A> const& vec)
{
    bool more = false;
    std::string str = "size:" + std::to_string(vec.size()) + " [";
    for (const T & item : vec)
    {
        if (more) { str += ", "; }
        str += std::to_string(item);
        more = true;
    }
    str += "]";
    return str;
}

void demo1()
{
    std::string dat[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
    std::vector<std::string> vs(dat, dat + 3);
    std::cout << range_to_string(vs) << std::endl;
}

void demo2()
{
    std::list<short> ls= {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::cout << range_to_string(ls) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    demo1();
    demo2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will fail for the map containers breaking your requirement.

Comment: Don't put this code in `std`. User your own namespace.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't have to make it a compiler error to call the function with a container that does not have I would just use

```
template<typename Container>
static std::string range_to_string(Container const& cont)
{
    bool more = false;
    std::string str = "size:" + std::to_string(cont.size()) + " [";
    for (const auto & item : cont)
    {
        if (more) { str += ", "; }
        str += std::to_string(item);
        more = true;
    }
    str += "]";
    return str;
}
```

This will work for any type that has `begin()`, `end()` and `size()`.  This will also work with any container that is not of the form `container_name<type, allocator>` like the map containers.

If someone passes something that does not have those there will be a compiler error on the line in the function where your function tries to use it.